# What is with all the extra junk in the migration file?

Tags: grails, database-migration, liquibase

I started testing out the grails database-migration plugin today.  I did an initial sync with the domain and then created a new changelog based on running the diff command.  This should have been as simple as renaming a column and (re)assigning the index to that column.  So I expect to see the following...

```
changeSet(author: "gdboling (generated)", id: "1306242441630-1") {
    addColumn(tableName: "manuscript_review_reviewer") {
        column(name: "reviewer_id", type: "bigint") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }
    }
}
changeSet(author: "gdboling (generated)", id: "1306242441630-2") {
    addPrimaryKey(columnNames: "manuscript_review_id, reviewer_id", constraintName: "manuscript_rePK", tableName: "manuscript_review_reviewer")
}
changeSet(author: "gdboling (generated)", id: "1306242441630-3") {
    dropPrimaryKey(tableName: "manuscript_review_reviewer")
}
changeSet(author: "gdboling (generated)", id: "1306242441630-4") {
    dropForeignKeyConstraint(baseTableName: "manuscript_review_reviewer", baseTableSchemaName: "manning_main_dev", constraintName: "FK9BEFBBB34863C659")
}
changeSet(author: "gdboling (generated)", id: "1306242441630-179") {
    addForeignKeyConstraint(baseColumnNames: "reviewer_id", baseTableName: "manuscript_review_reviewer", constraintName: "FK9BEFBBB3A28B41DF", deferrable: "false", initiallyDeferred: "false", referencedColumnNames: "id", referencedTableName: "user", referencesUniqueColumn: "false")
}
changeSet(author: "gdboling (generated)", id: "1306242441630-212") {
    dropColumn(columnName: "user_id", tableName: "manuscript_review_reviewer")
}
```

All that is well and good.  However, I'm also seeing a lot of dropIndex and createIndex blocks that have nothing to do with my change.  Anyone know why this would be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write up an issue at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASEMIGRATION with information to reproduce (database vendor and ideally some code and your database schema) and I'll see what can be done. Worst-case scenario is you'll need to collapse multiple elements into one - this is tricky stuff to automate and usually some human intervention is required.